# Do enemies have a similar magic resistance system to human players?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

I have been mainly using Fire & Ice based magic against enemies and I haven't seen much of difference on the damage caused.

My question is that are enemies having some kind of elemental resistance like players own characters?

Comment: I don't think we can really tell until we get access to the editor and see some stats about monsters. But I noticed the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some enemies that clearly are restitant to specific spells. The Uggardians for example are some sort of fire spirit and completely resist fire attacks. You can discover those from level 6 onwards.

Comment: That's true. They seem to be 100% resistant to the fire. I wonder if it is on/off system, also I am wondering if it is other way around that you could do double damage with ice?

Comment: I have the feeling that ice does a lot of damage to them however I do not have a good comparison whether poison or flash would do the same amount of damage if you have them on the same level.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure monsters do NOT have the same magic resistance system as players. For monsters, it seems to be all-or-nothing – uggardians are immune to fire, ice lizards to ice, and several monsters to poison (redcap herders plus all undead or mechanical monsters). I don't know of any immune to lightning (wyvern would be an obvious choice, but they're not).

I don't think uggardians are any more vulnerable to ice, or ice lizards any more vulnerable to fire. I haven't tested this though.